# Dataset of Rocket Launch Data

Tags: rockets, reference-request, raw-data

I needed actual data of any space rocket for a project that I am doing. Information regarding

1. Altitude or trajectory
2. Thrust
3. Sp. Impulse

etc was needed at each step of time.

It would be great of the data was in a tabulated manner.

I was not able to find any datasets online. It would be great if someone referred me to some resources where I can find the data.

Comment: What is included in "etc"?

Comment: Actually any of those 3 data points are fine, more details are always welcome. I will modify the rest of my experiment based on what's available

Comment: There are several related questions on the site already. Take a look at https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40074/6944 Not sure any one place has everything you're looking for, you may have to stitch it together.

Comment: There seems to be some interesting data there. Will look through those. Thanks a bunch